# dashboard need to called on visualforce

Tags: visualforce, dashboard

I need to call dashboard on visualforce page  and that visualforce page need to be called on home page of salesforce CRM.what i have done is written below.i have asked this question earlier but some respected one put this question on hold telling that question is not clear. 
the Visual force page that i am using as component is:-

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
 <apex:iframe src="/01Z28000000E2un" scrolling="true" id="theIframe"/>  
 </apex:page>
```

now what it is doing is sending me to this url:-

```
https://ap2.salesforce.com/01Z28000000E2un
```

leaving the page

```
https://ap2.salesforce.com/home/home.jsp.
```

However want to show this dashboard on the same page in the visualforce component.

Thanks...

Comment: Hey prabhat do you managed to solve the problem? I´m having the same problem and i would like to know if you were able to accomplish it and how. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below code, add "outputPanel"

```
 <apex:page showheader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:outputPanel id="SalesDashboard" >
         <script>
          location.href="https://ap2.salesforce.com/01Z28000000E2un?isdtp=vw";
         </script>
         </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. however still it is sending me  to the  dashboard url. leaving the home/home.jsp.